# Filtering many-to-one in Django template

Tags: python, django, orm

Let's say I have these models:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    headline     = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class ProfilePhoto(models.Model):
    photo        = models.ImageField(upload_to='profiles/photos')
    owner        = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='photos', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type_choices = (
        ('PR', 'Primary'),
        ('AD', 'Additional'),
    )
    type         = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=type_choices, default='AD')
```

and the following view:

```
def profiles(request):
    # Retrieve all active profiles
    profiles = Profile.objects.filter(status='AC').order_by('-updated_at')#.filter(photos__)
    context = {'profiles': profiles}

    return render(request, 'profiles.html', context)
```

and this in my template file:

```
{% for profile in profiles %}
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                    <p><a href="{{ profile.get_absolute_url }}">{{ profile.headline }}</a></p>
                    <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}profiles/thumbs/{{ profile.photos.first.photo }}">
            </div>
        </div>            
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Here I get one photo for each profile because of `profile.photos.first.photo` in the template but what I want instead is to select a single photo for each profile with the condition that it has a type of 'PR'. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [model method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#model-methods). Something like this:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    @property
    def primary_profile_photo(self):
        primary_photo = self.photos.filter(type='PR').order_by('?').first()
        return primary_photo.photo
```

That would get you a random (`order_by='?'`) photo, with type `PR`, that you could then access as `primary_profile_photo` in the template.

Comment: This is it! Thank you.